Movie with a tiny winged prince, swamp frogs, and heavy snow
Out of nowhere i suddenly have this vague memory of an animated movie i watched as a child (i was born 93 so the 90's but it might have been an old tape). This is what i can recall so far:
There were probably fairies of some kind and I particularly remember a tiny winged prince that had a sword.
It was mostly happening in a swamp and there were talking frogs.
I remember an intense scene towards the end where the prince is caught in a blizzard.
I have to know the name of this movie!

Sounds like Thumbelina from 1994.

A girl no bigger than her mother's thumb feels all alone in the world knowing she is the only person her size. Her wish for a companion at last comes true when the prince of the faerys arrives at her window sill. However, the niave Thumbelina's life goes downward from there when a toad kidnaps her.

She's saved by a small fairy prince who has a sword. Here's the trailer:




Your'e amazing! thanks! it was such a good movie!

Beat me to it by seconds! :D

@SystemDown Ah, sorry about that. ;) I'll hold my horses next time. Glad you found it, Saal.

Sounds like the Don Bluth version of Thumbelina which was produced in 1994.


It has fairies
Eponymous character get kidnapped by a family of toads.
Prince fairy gets caught in a winter storm

Here is the movie on YouTube:



